# Why can't Heroku build my app with dependencies?

Tags: go, heroku, dependencies, govendor

I have been working on a Go project and deploying it successfully with Heroku up until I added more packages.  My Heroku app is set up to deploy the main branch of my github repo, but it fails to build the app each time I push. This is the build log:

```
-----> Using buildpack: heroku/go
-----> Go app detected
-----> Fetching stdlib.sh.v8... done
-----> 
       Detected go modules via go.mod
-----> 
       Detected Module Name: my-heroku-app
-----> 
-----> New Go Version, clearing old cache
-----> Installing go1.17.3
-----> Fetching go1.17.3.linux-amd64.tar.gz... done
-----> Determining packages to install
       
       Detected the following main packages to install:
            my-heroku-app
       
-----> Running: go install -v -tags heroku -mod=vendor my-heroku-app 
webapp.go:6:2: cannot find package "." in:
    /tmp/build_1bdd9ef1/vendor/github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql
webapp.go:7:2: cannot find package "." in:
    /tmp/build_1bdd9ef1/vendor/github.com/gorilla/context
webapp.go:8:2: cannot find package "." in:
    /tmp/build_1bdd9ef1/vendor/github.com/gorilla/sessions
webapp.go:9:2: cannot find package "." in:
    /tmp/build_1bdd9ef1/vendor/golang.org/x/crypto/bcrypt
 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Go app.
 !     Push failed
```

Here is what my import statement looks like

```
import (
    "database/sql"
    "fmt"
    _ "github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql"
    "github.com/gorilla/context"
    "github.com/gorilla/sessions"
    "golang.org/x/crypto/bcrypt"
    "html/template"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "time"
    "unicode"
)
```

I have tried reading through the guides and documentation about govendor both at Heroku and on their github page, and as far as I can tell, I have done my setup correctly. I am currently using govendor and I have a vendor folder containing a json file in my repo that has the info for the dependencies. Everything works when I run it locally

update: I made a fresh repo with minimal code but as soon as I add a dependency I got the same error. I also tried deploying on Digital Ocean as well but I think they use the open source Heroku buildpack so I got the same error

update 2: I got a pared down version of the app working. The repo has no vendor directory or vendor json whatsoever despite using an external package (build log shows successful install of external package)

Comment: The `"."` is interesting, do you have any relative imports?

Comment: I don't believe so. My import statement in my main file looks like this                 `import (
 "database/sql"
 "fmt"
 _ "github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql"
 "github.com/gorilla/context"
 "github.com/gorilla/sessions"
 "golang.org/x/crypto/bcrypt"
 "html/template"
 "log"
 "net/http"
 "time"
 "unicode"
)`

Comment: very strange, not sure what's going on

Comment: Are you sure that the vendor directory is in the GitHub repo?

Comment: Yes I have a directory called vendor at the root level of the github repo and vendor.json is there